# Calcular idade em anos usando javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Como calcular a idade à partir de um input type="text" usando javascript?
Tenho o input:

```
<input style="width: 100%" type="text" readonly id="data_nascimento"/>
```

Como realizar esse cálculo? O formato da data é "01/01/2015".

Preciso converter em Object Date?
Como Realizar esse procedimento à partir do conteúdo do input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando apenas Javascript, você pode usar essa função:

```
function calcularIdade(aniversario) {
    var nascimento = aniversario.split("/");
    var dataNascimento = new Date(parseInt(nascimento[2], 10),
    parseInt(nascimento[1], 10) - 1,
    parseInt(nascimento[0], 10));

    var diferenca = Date.now() -  dataNascimento.getTime();
    var idade = new Date(diferenca);

    return Math.abs(idade.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kodrw5sj/

Comment: Obrigado pelo fiddle e pela atenção ao formato. Resposta Correta.

Answer (score 2):

Se você puder usar o momentjs, será mais simples fazer este cálculo.
Veja [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057497/moment-js-how-do-i-get-the-number-of-years-since-a-date-not-rounded-up):

```js
var birthDay = "1984-10-22";
var age = Math.floor(moment(new Date()).diff(moment(birthDay),'years',true));
console.log(age);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Verifica esta função. Acho que faz o que pretendes. Não tenho é a certeza em relação ao formato da data.

```js
function getAge(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}
```

```html
<input style="width: 100%" type="text" readonly id="data_nascimento" onBlur="getAge(this.value)" />
```

Comment: procure escreve o conteúdo dos links na sua resposta. Links podem ficar ficar off line e a sua resposta fica sem referência. Transcreva o conteúdo do link na sua resposta.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function idade(d1, d2) {
  d2 = d2 || new Date();
  var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
  return Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
}
console.log(idade(new Date(1998, 09, 3)));
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8ms8pmt/)

Answer (score -2):

```
function nasc (timestamp){
    const today = new Date()
    const nascDate = new Date(timestamp)

    let nasc = today.getFullYear() - nascDate.getFullYear()
    const month = today.getMonth() - nascDate.getMonth ()

    if (month < 0 || month == 0 && today.getDate() < nascDate.getDate()){
        nasc = nasc -1
    }

    return nasc
}
```

Comment: Por favor, descreva melhor sua resposta

Answer (score -2):

```
function idade (timestamp){ 
    const hoje = new Date() //estou pegando a data do dia 
    const diaDoNiver = new Date(timestamp) // aqui se refere ao dia do aniversário

    // a linha abaixo nos dá um retorno de idade, baseando-se apenas no ano, //subitraindo do ano atual o ano de nascimento ex: 2021-1990 = 31.  
    let idade = today.getFullYear() - diaDoNiver.getFullYear() //é necessário usar //o let pq vai ser alterado
    // na linha abaixo vamos verificar está no mês do aniversário
    const mes = today.getMonth() - diaDoNiver.getMonth ()
    
    //a linha abaixo valida o mês e a data exata do aniversário
    
    if (mes < 0 || mes == 0 && hoje.getDate() < diaDoNiver.getDate()){
        idade = idade -1 /// se não for o mês e a data exata diminue 1
    }

    return idade
}
```